Audio speed and fast forward option in MediaElement.js
I'm using MediaElement.js to play an audio from a File that is returned from the server. Below is my code.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Audio Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/4.2.16/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/4.2.16/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1></h1>
        <audio id="player" controls>
            <source src="/source" type="video/webm">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            console.log('Initializing MediaElementPlayer');
            const player = new MediaElementPlayer('player', {
                features: ['playpause', 'progress', 'volume', 'fullscreen', 'current', 'duration', 'speed'],
                speed: {
                    speeds: ['0.75', '1.00', '1.25', '1.50', '2.00'],
                    defaultSpeed: '1.00',
                    speedChar: 'x',
                    speedText: 'Speed'
                },
                success: function (mediaElement, originalNode, instance) {console.log('MediaElementPlayer initialized successfully');},
                error: function (mediaElement) {
                    fetch(mediaElement.src)
                        .then(response => {
                            if (!response.ok) {
                                return response.text().then(text => { throw new Error(text); });
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            document.getElementById('error-message').innerText = error.message;
                            document.getElementById('error-message').style.display = 'block';
                        });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

The file is in .webm format. I want to enable fast forward and speed selector in the audio player but its not showing. Can anyone assist me with this.
